# Copy a line of file character by character

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a line from a file character by character (trying to learn C, I know about frets, but not using this). But I keep getting a malloc error which I do not understand this is the part of my code that gives me a error:

```
char c;
char *buffer;

if ((buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100)) == NULL)
{
    DXLogError("Cannot allocated memory!");
    return 0;
}

while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        *buffer = '\0';
        break;
    }

    *buffer++ = c;

}

printf("End: %s", buffer);
free(buffer);
<--error here
```

Error: malloc: *** error for object 0x10aa1f833: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `*buffer++ = c` modified `buffer`. So `buffer` is no longer the pointer that you allocated. Thus, the error when you do the subsequent, `free(buffer);`.

In this case, you can use another temporary buffer pointer as your "moving" pointer, but keep `buffer` intact for the `free`.

The next problem you might run into is when you try to read/write a file that has a line with more than 100 bytes in it, since your buffer is only 100 bytes long. So you should check for that.

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing `buffer`, so the pointer you pass to `free` is not the one you allocated.

You have to store the initial pointer as well:

```
// your allocation code...
char * originalBuffer = buffer;

// your while loop...

free(originalBuffer);
```

Alternatively, you can use a second pointer for the loop and free using the original pointer, as suggested by lurker.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others said, you won't be able to print out the character-sequence you've stored inside the memory locations you have allocated with this, either. This is because you are passing the address of the last character, the `'\0'` into the `printf` as the second argument.

You should rather, again, be passing the address of the very first character; this is the address that you had stored into `buffer` at the very beginning.

Consider not violating `buffer` at all, using an additional variable, let's call it `i` an `int i;`, that you'll use for the index of the memory location.

```
buffer[0];  // equivalent to *(buffer + 0)
buffer[1];  // equivalent to *(buffer + 1)
buffer[2];
//...
buffer[99];
```

These are the memory locations you have in your hands, and you could wander inside them using the `i`, rather than violating the `buffer`.